# Can I embed an AWT Frame in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jframe

I need the functionality of AWT Frames for one component, but my main application window is a JFrame. Ideally this would be incorporated into my gridbaglayout.

Is there a way to do this short of tracking mouseclicks and "setLocationRealativeTo" with a window priority setting?

Update: I have added my media player into a "Canvas" to forgo the JInternalFrame or anything else, this component will be added to my main frame.

I am using a GridBagLayout, and Add all my buttons in the constructor of my main window, but I need to add this canvas afterward. Does anyone know how to add to a gridbaglayout post-constructor? I have tried "mainGUIclass.add(canvas,gridbagconstraints);" to no avail (since I just use "add(randomcomponent, gridbagconstraints);" in the constructor.

UPDATE: I think the root question here has changed for me, I will post a new one more to the point, thank you for all your help.

Comment: What AWT-related class *specifically* are you using? Are you sure that there are no Swing alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a [`JInternalFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)? For more information, see [How to Use Internal Frames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

Comment: I'm embedding a media player into it and I do not believe JInternalFrame has the capabilities I am looking for, I will update if I find otherwise.

Comment: It seems I can use JFrame to accomplish the same tasks, but so far I have been unable to get a JInternalFrame to show up on my regular JFrame...

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a "media player" then you add the media player component, not the frame to a Swing panel.

See: [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but widgets layout will be a pain in the a**.

More about it http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/